# How can I do to insert img between text? REACT-NATIVE

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm new in react-native and I want to know how can I do to insert image between text, I'm making a block note, so I want the option that writing, I can take a picture and then put it with the note, now I just have the basic structure of the block note I guess, just two inputs, one for the title and another one for the content, just want to try it first with a button that adds an image between the text and then save it, how can do that? Something like this:

[image]

Code:

```
save_Data = async() => {
    try {
        const array_notes = await AsyncStorage.getItem("array_notes");
        if (array_notes === null) {
            const array_notes = []; //creates a empty array to begin
            const new_note = {'note_number': array_notes.length + 1, 'title': this.state.title, 'content': this.state.content}; //create a new_note object, note_number will be the key for each note
            array_notes.push(new_note);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("array_notes", JSON.stringify(array_notes)); //using stringify to save the array 
        }else {
            const array_notes = JSON.parse(await AsyncStorage.getItem("array_notes")); //use parse to acces to the data of the array
            const new_note = {'note_number': array_notes.length + 1, 'title': this.state.title, 'content': this.state.content};
            array_notes.push(new_note);
            await AsyncStorage.setItem("array_notes", JSON.stringify(array_notes));
            const {params} = this.props.navigation.state; /* get the function passed by parameter through navigation (HOME.JS LINE 39)*/
            params.fetch_notes();  /*executes the function*/
        }
    }catch(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

render() {
    return  (
        <>
        <Text style = {this.styles.Text }>Welcome to Note!</Text>
        <View>
            <TextInput style = {this.styles.TextInput_title} placeholder = "Title" multiline = {true} maxLength = {80} onChangeText = {title => this.setState({title: title})}></TextInput>
            <TextInput style = {this.styles.TextInput_content} placeholder = "Content" multiline = {true} onChangeText = {content => this.setState({content: content})}></TextInput>
            <Button title = "Save" onPress = {this.save_Data}></Button>
       </View>
        <View style = {this.styles.back_Button}>
            <Button title = "Go back home" onPress = {() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")}></Button>
        </View>
        </>    
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround that'll preserve styles

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row', flexWrap:'wrap'}}>
    <Image
        style={styles.img}
        source={{uri: imageLink}} />
    <Text>
        {"sweet, this works"}
    </Text>
</View>
```

for using in text editor you can try this:

https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/rich-text-editor/image/

Comment: but can i still writing?

Comment: you can try https://ej2.syncfusion.com/react/documentation/rich-text-editor/image/

Answer (score 0):

`Text` can wrap `Image` component making the image inline with text.
Something like this can be used :

```
<Text>
 some text here
 <Image/>
 more text here
</text>
```

As a response to the comment what you can do is add some condition inside `text` something like this:

```
<Text>
 {this.state.content}
 {this.state.imageUri ? <Image source={{uri:this.state.imageUri}}/> : ''}
</text>
```

Comment: im doing this, but trying to concanetate it with the text i get and hi object Object, im doing this way: 

  add_Image = () => {
        let content = this.state.content;
        let img = <Image source = {require("../img/ny.png")}></Image>
        this.setState({content: content + img});
    }